# Problem with Oracle EBS concurrent program calling mailx

Tags: shell, mailx, oracle-ebs

We have an EBS 12.2 instance running on RHEL 8.x that was working fine until recently but has started getting blank emails when sending using mailx from a shell script. I can't determine anything different between calling the script locally and with the EBS concurrent program, but when the concurrent program calls mailx, a message gets queued in postfix that has no subject, no body, and no To: header. Has anybody ever seen something like this? I know it's not a lot to go on, but I'm hoping it will ring a bell for somebody.

The call looks like this, and works fine from the interactive shell:

```
cat /tmp/file.tmp | mailx -s "Subject of message for ${TODAY}" $recipient
```

I was expecting to see an email with contents, subject, etc. I've tried forcing different shells in the script header and confirmed that the file exists with the right contents even when invoked from EBS.

I've also tried variations of the mailx command to try and get it to misbehave in the same way outside the concurrent program, but without any luck.

Comment: Have you checked if this is a permissions problem?  I believe the concurrent manager runs as "applmgr" - have you tried running the shell as that user and/or ensuring the file is readable?

Comment: You may want to add a -vvv to the mailx command so you get a verbose log. When I have had issues with concurrent programs running shell scripts, I have captured additional information in the concurrent request log. I logged environment variables, which program was being called, file size, and file permissions. Include anything that might be different from the perspective of applmgr such as cfg files and keys.

Comment: Don't think it's a permissions issue, since I can sudo to "applmgr" and run the script from the shell without issue. I'll try adding the -vvv to see if anything else shows up.

Comment: Adding -vvv caused it to send the delivery report to the local mailbox. The output of the two looks identical up to "Part 3" which contains the message headers. 
The good message has:
Return-Path, Received, Date, To, Subject, User-Agent, MIME-Version, Content-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Message-Id, From

The bad message has:
Return-Path, Received, Message-Id, Date, From

The contents of the common headers seem to be substantially equivalent.